# How do I access $resource from an angularjs controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm running a Rails 4 application with angular.  When I run the following code, the error I get (in Firefox console) is *$resource is not defined*.

1)  Is $resource not a global variable?  How do I access it?
2)  How do I call the API endpoint "/admin/update_something" properly from the controller on the submit event from the html form?

Today is my second day of learning angularjs, so I'm trying to learn the conventions.

**html/haml:**

```
%section{"ng-app"=>"bctApp", "ng-controller" => "bctCtr"}
  %form{:name => "bctForm", "ng-submit" => "bctSubmit($event)"}
    %table
      %thead
        %tr
          %th bct ID 
      %tbody
        %tr 
          %td
            %input{:type => "button", :value => "Add bct ID", "ng-click"=>"addbctIdField()"}
            %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Save Changes"}
        %tr{"ng-repeat" => "bct_id in bct_ids track by $index"}  
          %td 
            %input{:type =>"text", :value=>"{{ bct_id }}" }
            %input{:type =>"button", :value=>"Remove", "ng-click"=>"removebctIdField($index)"}
```

**angularjs controller:**

```
function Admin($resource) {
    return $resource('/admin/update_something', 
      { },
      { update_list: {
          method: "POST",
          isArray: true 
        }
      }
   );
  }

  function bctCtr($scope) {
    $scope.bct_ids = gon.bct_ids;
    $scope.addbctIdField = function() {
      $scope.bct_ids.unshift($scope.bct_id_val);
    }
    $scope.removebctIdField = function(index) {
      $scope.bct_ids.splice(index, 1);
    }
    $scope.bctSubmit = function() {
      var bctUpdate = new Admin();
      bctUpdate.update_list({}, $scope.bct_ids);

    }

  }

  var bctApp = angular.module('bctApp', ['ngResource']);
  bctApp.controller('bctCtr', bctCtr);
  bctApp.factory('Admin', ['$resource', Admin]);

})(angular);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Admin as a parameter in your controller declaration in addition to $scope.
Then when you use it you can directly call Admin.update... You don't have to use new Admin() (and should not do it IMO).
Don't forget to inject it below.

The problem is you are using Admin but not asking angular for it so $resource cannot be injected.

Answer (score -1):

Please check that you injected ngResource module as a dependency to your application, i.e.

```
var app=angular.module("myApp", ["ngResource"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why you are getting an error that says `$resource is not defined`. I've created a plunkr and it works!

Can you let me know, which line of code it says?

Here is the working [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QMU9mmUZxbUVQtZ6EHFt?p=preview)

```
function Admin($resource) { 
  return $resource('/admin/update_something', 
    { },
    { update_list: 
      {
        method: "POST",
        isArray: true 
      }
    }
 );
}

function bctCtr($scope, Admin) {
  console.log(Admin)
}

var bctApp = angular.module('bctApp', ['ngResource']);
bctApp.controller('bctCtr', bctCtr);
bctApp.factory('Admin', ['$resource', Admin]);
```